# Assume you have to add key: list[values] to a dictionary if key does not exist and add to list[values] if it exists. Is there a more efficient way?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

```
if key in dict
    dict[key].extend([values*])
else:
    dict[key] = [values*]

//PSEUDOCODE
```

If it makes any difference, I a using JavaScript and have to store key value pairs in a class dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if key not in dict:
    dict[key] = []
dict[key].extend(values)
```

(Though don't use `dict` as a variable name in python.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a default dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def default_value():
    return []

dict = defaultdict(default_value)
dict[key].append(5)
```

If there is not value for that key when appending, a new key value pair will be created with an empty list as the value.